# Read through a feature class and export each feature BY ROW to KML via arcpy

Tags: arcpy, kml, export

I have a geodatabase feature class of a polygon with multiple rows, where each row represents an individual polygon. I need to loop through each one of these polygons (rows) and export them to a KML file. What would be the best approach to deal with this using arcpy?

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange! As a new user please take the [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn about our focused Q&A format. Please note that questions regarding code expect you to include a code snippet or what you've already tried, otherwise it may be closed as off-topic.

Comment: The general tools you can use for this are: `arcpy.da.SearchCursor`, `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management` and `arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion`.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but general process:

```
import arcpy
# Determine range of FIDs (Shapefile) or ObjectIDs (GDB feature class)
polyg = "PATH_TO_FEATURECLASSS"
polygIDS = [x[0] for x in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(polyg, ["OBJECTID"])]
# Alternative method that also works:
# with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(polyg, ["OBJECTID"]) as cursor:
#    polgyIDS = [row[0] for row in cursor]
# Loop through rows, creating layer each time
for i in polygIDs:
    whereclause = """{} = {}""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(polyg, "OBJECTID"), i)
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(polyg,"polyg_lyr{}".format(i), whereclause)
    # Setup Output name / destination
    outKML = "PATHTOKML{}".format(i) #unique name by ObjectID
    # Output KML / KMZ file 
    arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion("polyg_lyr{}".format(i), outKML)
    # Delete layer to free memory
    arcpy.Delete_management("polyg_lyr{}".format(i))
```

References:
[Layer to KML](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/layer-to-kml.htm)

Comment: `polygIDS = [x[0] for x in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(polyg, ["OBJECTID"]]` = invalid syntax. You can keep the disclaimer in your post "not tested", but whatever if you want to role out my edit that _did_ work.

Comment: Hmm, I attempted to edit but it seems to have fallen back. Two possible valid syntaxes, both with list comprehension. I'll list both for clarity:  `polygIDS = [x[0] for x in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(polyg, ["OBJECTID"])]` (Added an ending ")").  or `with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(polyg, ["OBJECTID"]) as cursor: polygIDS = [row[0] for row in cursor]`.

Comment: what exactly would go for datasource and field? here:

whereclause = """{} = {}""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource, field), i)

would that be polyg and field OBJECTID?

Comment: Yes, but double-check that the fieldname is OBJECTID in your source (for any of the rows that reference that field).